# hide second dropdown, until a selection made in first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I believe this question has been answered before but unfortuantely the answer provided isn't working for me.
(I am fairly new to Jquery/Javascript)

I'm using this [jsfiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/1474/) to try and solve my problem.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="EU-selector">
    <p>For EU:</p>
    <div class="dropdown" id="arrowdown">
        <select name="eu-model" id="eu-model">
            <option value="">Select your model:</option>
            <option value="1">Beetle</option>
            <option value="2">Caddy4</option>
            <option value="3">CC</option>
            <option value="4">E-Golf</option>
            <option value="5">Eos</option>
            <option value="6">Golf 7</option>
            <option value="7">Golf Cabrio</option>
            <option value="8">Golf GTI</option>
            <option value="9">Golf R</option>
            <option value="10">Golf Sportsvan</option>
            <option value="11">Golf Variant</option>
            <option value="12">Jetta</option>
            <option value="13">Passat</option>
            <option value="14">Polo</option>
            <option value="15">Scirocco</option>
            <option value="16">Sharan</option>
            <option value="17">T6</option>
            <option value="18">Tiguan</option>
            <option value="19">Touran</option>
        </select>
        <div class="eu-year">
            <div class="beetle">
                <select class="beetle-year">
                    <option value="">Select your year:</option>
                    <option value="1">2015</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="caddy4">
                <select class="caddy4-year">
                    <option value="">Select your year:</option>
                    <option value="1">2015</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically, when you choose a model, it will then show the 'year' dropdown.
I do wish to add another dropdown (3rd tier) for 'Systems' but I want to get over this hurdle first.

I've added in my CSS in this [jsfiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/2cqespL2/)

Also, the CSS for .dropdownarrow is supposed to flip the down arrow image (couldn't find out how to upload - maybe you can't?) to an up arrow on click, but stay 'active' until you click off the dropdown menu (or select an option - to then go to 2nd dropdown).

Here's the JS I've included within the HTML code (I will move it to it's own .js file later)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#eu-model').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.eu-year').children().hide();
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { 
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); 
    }
}).trigger('change');
})
```

Can anyone advise to where I'm going wrong?
All help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<div id="EU-selector">
    <p>For EU:</p>
    <div class="dropdown" id="arrowdown">
        <select name="eu-model" id="eu-model">
            <option value="">Select your model:</option>
            <option value="1">Beetle</option>
            <option value="2">Caddy4</option>
            <option value="3">CC</option>
            <option value="4">E-Golf</option>
            <option value="5">Eos</option>
            <option value="6">Golf 7</option>
            <option value="7">Golf Cabrio</option>
            <option value="8">Golf GTI</option>
            <option value="9">Golf R</option>
            <option value="10">Golf Sportsvan</option>
            <option value="11">Golf Variant</option>
            <option value="12">Jetta</option>
            <option value="13">Passat</option>
            <option value="14">Polo</option>
            <option value="15">Scirocco</option>
            <option value="16">Sharan</option>
            <option value="17">T6</option>
            <option value="18">Tiguan</option>
            <option value="19">Touran</option>
        </select>
        <div class="eu-year">
            <div data-value="1">
                <select>
                    <option value="">Select your year of your Beetle:</option>
                    <option value="1">2015</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-value="2">
                <select>
                    <option value="">Select your year of your Caddy4:</option>
                    <option value="1">2015</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eu-model').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value.length) {
            $('.eu-year > div').hide();
            $('.eu-year > div[data-value="' + this.value + '"').show();
        }
    });
})
```

CSS

```
.eu-year > div {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: With this code i base the year select on the value from the model selector by using the `data-value` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working, even in the jsfiddle. =/

Comment: Try it on your page, i just did in a clean document and it worked :) Also make sure your css does not ruin anything for your, try to disable all css but the one that i posted and see if the script works as it supposed to, then edit the style

Comment: The reason it did not work in the fiddle is because you did not include jquery. Try adding external sources to the left by pasting this `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js` And press the +

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thanks very much! I think it was my .dropdown css that was affecting it. Thanks again!

Comment: One last thing, the dropdown itself is hidden until a model is selected.

but, when adding the same css style to .eu-year (as there is on .dropdown) the styling shows. even when the 2nd dropdown is hidden.

I realize it was 'overflow: hidden' causing the problem previously.

Comment: Post a new fiddle if the issue remains and i'll look into it

Comment: Hi Johnathan,
Okay so, it works (including the styling) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bctride/2cqespL2/6/).
but say you select beetle > 2015. then change the model to something else, (whether it has a year dropdown or not) then switch back to beetle, the 2nd dropdown doesn't reset to 'Select your year:' but stays on the previous selection (of 2015)...

also, on page refresh, it resets the second dropdown to be hidden, but doesn't reset the top dropdown back to 'Select your mode:'.
Sorry for the 20 questions! Thanks for your time!